# Как создать wsdl файл из готовых классов джава?

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, soapui

Как создать или сгенерировать wsdl файл из готовых классов на джава в Intelij idea для soap ui?Я пересмотрел все материалы но там готовые wsdl файлы там нету обьяснение как это делать а берут готовые wsdl

Comment: Справка к Idea: [1) JVM frameworks / Java Enterprise / Web services / Generate WSDL document from Java (Ultimate)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generating-wsdl-document-from-java-code.html); [2) Generate WSDL from Java dialog (Required plugin: Jakarta EE: Web Services (JAX-WS))](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-wsdl-from-java-dialog.html)

Comment: Спасибо за справку пойду чекну!Ракмет)